# can't call the apply function defined when new a trait

Tags: scala

```
object test {
  trait Test {
    def apply() = {
      println("calling apply in trait test")
      this
    }
  }
  object Test {
    def apply(f: Int => String): Test = {
      println("calling apply in object Test")
      new Test {
        println("test123")
        def apply(a: Int) = f(a)  // this apply function should be available when call Test(f)?
      }
    }
  }
  def fun(a:Int)=a.toString
  val f=fun _
  val a=Test(f)
  a()
  a(1) // why this failed? a is created by calling Test(f) which is actually 
       //calling apply function of object Test, and that function return a Test
       //with an addition function of apply(a:Int). And a(1) is actually calling 
       //apply(1), but why it doesn't compile? 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your signature:

```
def apply(f: Int => String): Test = { … }
```

restricts the result to being seen as a `Test` trait, which does not include your new `apply`. By omitting the result type, the returned object will be a `Test+apply` and it will do what you expect it to:

```
def apply(f: Int => String) = { … }
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this fails is that your type `Test` is defined with an `apply` method that takes an empty parameter list. With `new Test { ... }` you create an anonymous subclass of `Test`. Although you overload `apply` with another version that takes an `Int` argument, the return type of your object's `apply` method is just `Test`. So from the outside, that overloaded method is not visible.

To illustrate your problem:

```
trait Foo

def mkFoo(): Foo = new Foo { def bar = 1234 }

val f = mkFoo()
f.bar  // we don't know anything about bar
```

Simply define your trait `Test` to include the other `apply` method:

```
trait Test {
  def apply() = {
    println("calling apply in trait test")
    this
  }

  def apply(i: Int): String  // abstract
}
```

**Edit**: As a matter of completeness, if you use a 'refined' return type as shown in @samuel tardieu's answer, technically you use a 'structural type' which comes with a bit of a performance penality, as the method will be invoked using runtime reflection.